# Colocar espaço entre duas colunas bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

As colunas do Bootstrap que ficam dentro da `div` com a classe `.row` ficam coladas ( http://prntscr.com/io5hbg ). Porém eu gostaria de "desgrudar" elas de alguma forma, colocando um espaçamento entre elas de pelo menos de 20px.

Já tentei com css ( usando margin na class da coluna: http://prntscr.com/io5kyk ), já tentei usar mais `div.row` em tudo mas não resolveu.

Exemplo de como fica grudado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código: https://hastebin.com/savuwuzifo.xml

Comment: As colunas ficam coladas, mas elas possuem `padding` configurado, ou seja, o conteúdo dentro delas já vai ficar com o espaço que você deseja.

Comment: Pior que não, @Oeslei, olhe: http://prntscr.com/io6ypm src: http://prntscr.com/io6yzt

Comment: é no Bootstrap 4 né?

Comment: @LeandroRR pela tag da pergunta é Bootstrap3... Posta sua dica ai, sempre é valido ter outra opção.

Comment: valew hugo, e desculpe me qualquer coisa

Comment: @LucasJosivan coloca o `background` na tag `p`, ou até melhor, coloca uma `div` entre a `col-*` e o `p` específica para isso. É parecido com a resposta do @hugocsl, mas acredito que não é necessário colocar outra vez a classe `col-*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara tem uma técnica que pode te atender. Ela como uma coluna de 12 dentro de uma coluna de 3, dessa forma vc fica com um padding dentro da coluna de 3 e cria esse espaço entre as colunas.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-bg-color">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Veja o exemplo.** *(como falei não precisa de CSS é só aninhar as `divs col-` )*

***Execute em "Página toda" para ver melhor, pois está responsivo e fica pequeno dessa forma.***

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {background-color: #00192f !important; color: aliceblue !important;}
.logo  {max-width: 30% !important; height: 30% !important; margin-left: 30px;}
.separador {border-bottom: thin solid #5a5a5a !important;}
.espaco-cima {padding-top: 15px;}
.espaco-tudo {padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;}
.pqn {font-size: 10px;}
.col-bg-color {background-color: #00213e !important; color: aliceblue !important; border: thin solid #5a5a5a; border-radius: 10px;}
.margin {margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
#login-dp{min-width: 250px; padding: 14px 14px 0; overflow: hidden; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.9);}
#login-dp .help-block{font-size:12px}
#login-dp .bottom{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.9); border-top:1px solid #ddd; clear:both; padding:14px;}
#login-dp .form-group {margin-bottom: 10px;}
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .logo  {max-width: 20% !important; height: 20% !important;}
    #login-dp{background-color: inherit; color: #fff;}
    #login-dp .bottom{background-color: inherit; border-top:0 none;}
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background-color: #000867;}
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 6px; background: #000867;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: #1400ff;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid">
            
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-bg-color">
                    <div class="row">
                            <a><img src="https://i.imgur.com/j03ymqv.jpg" style="width:100%; height: auto; border-radius: 10px;" alt="Campeonato Zula"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row separador espaco-tudo">
                            <h4>Seletiva Zula Brasil Mundial</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row separador espaco-tudo">
                            <p>Criador: Zula Pro League</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row espaco-tudo">
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>Data</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">19/03/18&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>Horário</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">22:00&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>&nbsp;Organizadora</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">ZPL</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>&nbsp;Vagas</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-bg-color">
                    <div class="row">
                            <a><img src="https://i.imgur.com/j03ymqv.jpg" style="width:100%; height: auto; border-radius: 10px;" alt="Campeonato Zula"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row separador espaco-tudo">
                            <h4>Seletiva Zula Brasil Mundial</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row separador espaco-tudo">
                            <p>Criador: Zula Pro League</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row espaco-tudo">
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>Data</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">19/03/18&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>Horário</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">22:00&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>&nbsp;Organizadora</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">ZPL</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>&nbsp;Vagas</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-bg-color">
                    <div class="row">
                            <a><img src="https://i.imgur.com/j03ymqv.jpg" style="width:100%; height: auto; border-radius: 10px;" alt="Campeonato Zula"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row separador espaco-tudo">
                            <h4>Seletiva Zula Brasil Mundial</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row separador espaco-tudo">
                            <p>Criador: Zula Pro League</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row espaco-tudo">
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>Data</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">19/03/18&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>Horário</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">22:00&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>&nbsp;Organizadora</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">ZPL</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>&nbsp;Vagas</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-bg-color">
                    <div class="row">
                            <a><img src="https://i.imgur.com/j03ymqv.jpg" style="width:100%; height: auto; border-radius: 10px;" alt="Campeonato Zula"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row separador espaco-tudo">
                            <h4>Seletiva Zula Brasil Mundial</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row separador espaco-tudo">
                            <p>Criador: Zula Pro League</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row espaco-tudo">
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>Data</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">19/03/18&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>Horário</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">22:00&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>&nbsp;Organizadora</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">ZPL</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn"><strong>&nbsp;Vagas</strong></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px !important; border-top: none !important;" class="pqn text-right">20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: tem como curtir duas vezes a resposta ?

Comment: Haha valeu @Otto , esse truque quebra um galho mesmo!

Comment: Galho nada quebra a arvore toda kkk

Comment: Caraca que sensacional! Eu passei uma semana pra tentar arrumar isso kkkk obrigado mesmo, funcionou perfeitamente. Melhor técnica!!